# Repository pattern and web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

Hi i learned web api 2 recently and i am working on a sample project now.I am following layered architecture in my project.This is the flow

controller=>Business Layer=>Data Layer

Now i read some article about the repository pattern which sound better nowadays.

i saw the flow like

controller=>services=>repository

Is there any significant difference between the two flows?
As a beginner which style of architecture should i flow?
Can someone help me to understand these patterns?

Comment: Repository is just a different way of implementing DataAccessLayer. In your data access layers, instead of using ADO.NET classes, you can use repositories backed up by some ORM such as Entity Framework or NHibernate. The same way services layer can be called your business layer where you have service class instead of manager classes. But both of them will have code which represents your business logic such as validation and they are integrated with DAL or repository for data retrieval and store.

Comment: Whatever approach you choose, some of the basic principles are applicable to both of them such as design by contract, inversion of control, dependency injection etc.

Comment: So Services=Business Layer and repository=Data Layer? Am using Entity Framework so what the benefit if i change to second flow mentioned?

Comment: The advantage is that your code is easier to test, separation of concerns, it's DRY etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use services with repository you should make it generic and use Unit of Work (UOW) so you don't repeat yourself with CRUD actions on every entity. Then add some object relational mapper (ORM) like Entity Framework. It is prefered that you also use domain objects for storing your logic there, and make the services return data transfer objects (DTO), because best practice is to keep your services small and clean. Then you also need to include some mapping tool/logic to map DTO to Domain objects.

And you see where this is all going. Suddenly you have far more complexity and obstructions than you need. Because only one thing that customer care about is quality of your product not some fancy architecture.

But as project grow it is much more important to have proper architecture, automatic tests etc. , so it is valid in large projects. If you want to experiment and learn it is great opportunity, but if you have running application in production, i would rather not make that big changes.

**TLDR**: they are both valid